# When someone goes forward out of turn in a line

Tags: sentence-construction

Let's suppose you are standing in a line for something. Someone comes and wants to go forward out of line without considering others' orders.
What would you say him normally in order to ask him stand **at the end of the line**?

> Excuse me, you can't go **forward** out of turn! __________________.

a. Go behind the line please. 
b. Go to the end of the line please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I will address you question.

"Go *behind* the line" does not sound like what you intend. If you imagine the line to be a like a wall, then asking someone to go behind it means going to one side or the other, not one of the ends. That's how I'm interpreting it. Actually, "*get* behind the line" might be OK, but I'm not 100% confident at this moment.

"Go *to the end* of the line" has the intended meaning. Lines have ends and you want them to go the end for the people who are last. Alternatively, you could also say, "go to the *back* of the line."

Next, your usage of "forward" is understandable, but it just does not seem particularly idiomatic to me. Actually, "you can't go out of turn" (without "forward") sounds fine to me.

Alternatively, you could say "you can't *cut the/in line*".

> [cut in line](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cut+in+line)
>   To enter somewhere in the middle of a line of people who are waiting for something, rather than standing behind the last person, as is customary. Primarily heard in US.
>   *Hey, don't cut in line! Get behind the rest of us!*
>   (TFD)

I'm sure there are a number alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

If you jump the line/ queue, you go ahead of the other people in a line/queue.

So you can say,

Excuse me, you can't jump the line/queue.

but to be polite, you can say:

Would you please go to the back of the line?

would you mind going to the back of the line?

The phrases "go to the behind of" and "go to the end of"  are also correct grammatically, but the phrase "go to the back of" is far more idiomstic.

Comment: Thank you @Khan for the good point. I forgot about that idiom. Just, could you please let me know how shall I ask the guy to get at the end of the line / gueue?

Comment: Be careful if the person is bigger than you.

Comment: I am British; I would just glare or roll my eyes. Seriously, it is not good to start arguments in public places. The other person might be mentally unstable and be carrying a knife. Also, he (it is usually a male) is committing a breach of good manners, but ordering him to go to the back of the queue is also bad manners. Giving orders to strangers is a way of starting fights. Better to keep quiet for the sake of a few minutes. The person serving may say "wait your turn".

Comment: @Michael Harvey, I appreciate your comments.

Comment: The person servicing the line or attending the counter should have be the authority and take care of these situations. If you are really upset, you can address them and complain. It is indeed an annoying situation to be in, but giving orders to people without having authority can  be even less acceptable than jumping the line.